# Given f holomorphic on $B_1(0)$ and $max_{z \in C_r(0)} |f(z)| \to 0$ as $r \to 1$. Show f is identically 0.

Tags: complex-analysis, cauchy-integral-formula

I have tried to use cauchy integral formula and the deformation theorem but that got nowhere: I got $f(z_0) = max_{z \in C_r'(z_0)}|f(z)|$ where $r' > 0$ such that $B_r'(z_0) \subset B_1(0)$.
Note: $C_r(x)$ is notation for a circle of radius $r$ and centre $x$ in the complex plane

Let me outline my attempt further. I have attempted to show that $\forall \varepsilon > 0: \forall w \in B_1(0): |f(w)|<\varepsilon$. I let $\varepsilon$ and $w$ be free, I evaluate f(w) at some $C_r(0)$ such that $B_{|w|}(0) \subset \mathrm{Int}(C_r(0))$. From the Cauchy integral formula, I have
$$
f(w) = \frac{1}{2i\pi}\int_{C_r(0)}\frac{f(z)}{z-w}dz
$$
From which I tried to deform into something that would cancel out the denominator but that led me nowhere. I have also tried just straight up bashing it but that went nowhere too.

Comment: OP says below that they are after a solution without using the maximum modulus principle.

Answer (score 1):

For $0<r<1$ and $z_0\in B_r(0)$, Cauchy's integral formula yields
$$f(z_0)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int\limits_{C_r(0)}\frac{f(z)}{z-z_0}\,dz$$
Taking absolute values and using the triangle inequality for integrals, we obtain
\begin{align*}
|f(z_0)|&\leq\frac{1}{2\pi }\int\limits_{C_r(0)}\frac{|f(z)|}{|z-z_0|}\,dz\\
&\leq \frac{1}{2\pi }\int\limits_{C_r(0)}\frac{\max\limits_{\zeta\in C_r(0)}|f(\zeta)|}{r-|z_0|}\,dz\\
&=\frac{r}{r-|z_0|}\max\limits_{\zeta\in C_r(0)}|f(\zeta)|
\end{align*}
Taking $r\to 1^-$ now proves the desired result.

**Edit:** Changed $r$ in denominator to $r-|z_0|$.

Comment: I have gotten to the part right before the integrand with the $r$ denominator. Can you explain how $|z-z_0|$ yields $r$?

Comment: Right, I realised that I made a mistake. I have edited the answer to correct it.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on the taking r to 1? i have gotten to the conditional that for some delta, 1-delta < r < 1 implies max|f(z)| < epsilon*((r-|z0|)/r) which if r satisfies the antecedent, the result naturally falls out. my question is how about the case when r is smaller than 1-delta?

Comment: ok i think i got it. its just me messing up my quantifiers

Answer (score 0):

Let $\epsilon >0$ there exists $r_0\in (0,1)$ such that $|f(z)| <\epsilon$ whenever $|z|=r$ and $r >r_0$. By Maximum Modulus Principle, $|f(z)| \le \epsilon$ whenever $|z|\le r$. Since this  holds for all $r >r_0$ it follows that $|f(z)| \le \epsilon$ for all $z$. Since $\epsilon >0$ is arbitrary it follows that $f(z)=0$ for all $z$.

Comment: Thank you. However, the maximum-modulus principle is supposed to be something we learn later; I do not have access to the machinery of the principle unfortunately. This is the best I could do without the principle.

Comment: OK. I will leave this answer for the benefit of others.